# Sorting an array of structs by string

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to sort an array of structs using selection sort and pointers, but I'm having some trouble.

When I try to print the array out to see if the names are sorted, all the names are sorted except for the one in the first position which remains where it is (unsorted).

```
/*
   all is the unordered array of struct; pLast is pointer to the last struct in array.
*/
void sortArray(CASE* all, CASE* pLast)
{
  CASE* current;
  CASE* walker;
  CASE* smallest;
  CASE temp;


  for(current = all; current < pLast; current++)
  {
    smallest = current;

    for (walker = current + 1; walker <= pLast; walker++)
    {
      if(strcmp(walker->name, smallest->name) < 0 )
        smallest = walker;
    }
    temp = *current;
    *current = *smallest;
    *smallest = temp;
  }

  for(walker = all; walker <= pLast; walker++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", walker->name);
  }  

  return;
}
```

Any tips?

Thanks

Edit: major revision that allows the names to be printed, but not fully sorted

Comment: My first thought is that you need to initialize `smallest` before you use it. The first time your loop runs, it will have some random pointer value which you are dereferencing with `smallest->name`. As soon as you do that, who knows what'll happen?

Comment: I initialized it to all so that the first run would make the strcmp return 0; however, the same problem still occurs.

Comment: Secondly, the selection sort algorithm has a loop within a loop -- you have the inner loop which is responsible for finding the `smallest` item, but no outer loop.

Comment: This sorting algorithm is broken anyway (a bubble sort has 2 embedded loops).

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize I missed the outer loop. Will make changes now. Thanks!

Comment: By the way: why write a sorting function when there's a `qsort()` in libc?

Comment: @H2CO3 Learning how to code right now :]

Comment: Modified the code to include outer loop, but still running into same error.

Comment: look carefully: the swap should not be inside the inner loop. In other words, first you find the smallest element, and *then* you make a swap.

Comment: If you still get a segmentation fault, I'd first try to make sure that my `->name` pointers are not broken. You could do that printing the unsorted array (i.e. `for(walker = all; walker <= pLast; walker++) printf("%s\n", walker->name);`) before you start sorting.

Comment: I still get the segmentation fault. I've tried printing unsorted and it works. Only sorted gives me segmentation faults. I'll keep looking into this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are probably getting segmentation faults because you are trying to swap `smallest` with `walker`. However, after the inner loop has finished, `walker` is a pointer to the next CASE *after the end of the array* -- i.e. `walker == pLast + 1` is true -- and that's a bad pointer to memory you probably don't own. Hence the segmentation fault. (FYI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

Comment: You are such a beast... thanks man. Changed the swap so that we're swapping current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a simple algorithm, selection sorts always look something like this:

```
function selection_sort(arr):
  for i in 0..len(arr)-1:
    smallest = i
    for j in i+1..len(arr)-1:
      if arr[j] < arr[smallest]:
        smallest = j
    swap i and smallest.
```

An implementation will still use this format (or very close) if using pointers.

FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to use qsort?

Unfortunately you to not write what `struct CASE*` is; we just know it contains a field name

So you can write a comparison function like:

```
int case_struct_comparison_function (const void * v1, const void * v2) {
  const struct CASE * case_1 = v1;
  const struct CASE * case_2 = v2;
  return  strcmp(case_1->name, case_2->name);
}

qsort(arr, size_of_arr, sizeof(struct CASE), case_struct_comparison_function);
```

It's untested but should give you an idea.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to code right now using pointers/structs so I want to stick to the problem.

Comment: As you can see I'm using all kind of pointers in this cuntion. I use the pointer to a CASE struct, dereference a ponter in strcmp and am using a function pointer as parameter ;-) Anywa I do get what you want to do. But I asked is there any reaon not to use qsort...

Comment: @Friedrich To an experienced C programmer, those usages don't really stand out as being something to notice, "dereferencing a pointer in `strcmp()`" really is nothing special. I'm not saying this to "keep you down", but just trying to point out that while to you, your code is obviously needlessly convoluted because you want to practice, to someone else it might be needlessly convoluted and should be changed to something simpler. :)

Comment: It is not convulted, it used the means C gives us. And not it's hardly simple to get a good search function implemented. It took even years to get quicksort right and even binary search was "once" problematic. So no I disagree with your comment.